# Holidays and sundays: database or function validation?

Tags: database, cordova, validation, date, mobile

I have a web application up and running, and right now my bosses wanted me to do some updates, but also they wanted to be able to use some information using a mobile device.

I am in charge of the web application for desktop and they hired a third party developers to get the mobile app done, I thought they were going to program it in Android, but they are using xamarin or apache cordova, which for me is the same, because I know eventually I will have to change or update that application.

The matter here is that the mobile app developers are asking me to save the sundays in the same table I am storing the holidays,because according to them using functions to calculate mondays is degrading the app's performance a lot.

I am not expert, but if they are using something like apache cordova or ionic, they are making an hybrid application, which basically is a web page, so, this past weekend I made a quick test, listing all the main info and showing all the data related to that item in another view.  It was my first time programming a sort of optimized web page for mobiles, using basics of responsive web desing, you it is worth noticing that being my first time, I could have not done any kind of real optimization that professional programmers in that particular area do, and it seemed to me that it was pretty decent.

I forgot to mention, the holidays and sundays are not showing anywhere, they are part of calculations to get some fees' amount a customer must pay, and as you should know, being mobile, they do not show all at once, but one by one because the main list shows the name of the customer, his/her account number, and the total amount to pay, then you click it and go to the detailed view.

So, long story short, according to your experience, would you save the sundays info in the database or use javascript/php functions to operate with them?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It really depends over how many weeks you run your calculation over, otherwise it shouldn't be.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your issue: you've got customers who pay based on # of days. A table lists holidays that don't incur charges. Now you also want to avoid incurring charges on Sundays (or Mondays? You use both in the post). I understand putting holidays in an exclusion table since they may move around a lot, but something that occurs weekly? No, I wouldn't do that at all. I fear they are using a naive approach to calculate recurring exclusions when it should be a fairly simple expression instead that would operate faster than any table access ever would.

Comment: @Eric When anyone loads the detailed view the calculations can vary, from a month to 2 years, but usually the customers pay in less than 6 months.

Comment: @KerriShotts Sorry, I just saw that, it is sundays, in the main web application sundays are excluded.

Yes, it is what I said, holidays usually change, but sundays (or any other day) can get validated with functions like in javascript: Date.getDay() that returns 0 to 6.

I talked about that with a friend and he also agrees with what you said, and I am going to put sundays in the db holidays table, so I am not the reason they fall behind schedule.  

Thanks for your comments.